# Error HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3 al ejecutar una consulta en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Es un error un poco extraño. Al ejecutar una consulta sobre ciertas tablas de una base de datos MySQL desde el driver de Java, el sistema lanza el siguiente error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
> at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
> at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
> at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
> at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.createFromTimestamp(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:97)
> at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.createFromTimestamp(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:44)
> ...
> ```

Sin embargo, cuando lanzamos la misma consulta sobre Workbench, la consulta se ejecuta correctamente.

Estamos utilizando la versión 8.0.17 de mysql. En cuanto al driver java, estamos utilizando la versión 8.0.17.

En [este post](https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-time-zone-configuration-using-hibernate/) hemos visto que puede tratarse de un problema de configuración del parámetro **serverTimeZone** de la base de datos, sin embargo, en la cadena de conexión ya especificamos el timezone como Europe/Madrid:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mysqldb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="200" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="3000"
           username="..." password="..." driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bbdd"
           connectionProperties="zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL;useSSL=false;characterEncoding=utf8;useUnicode=true;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras verificar que no se trata de un problema de configuración del parámetro **serverTimeZone**, es posible que dicha fecha no sea correcta ([ver post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352091/2131029)).

En nuestro caso, el problema era que había un campo de fecha cuyo valor coincidía en fecha y hora con la fecha y hora del cambio de horario a verano, es decir, "29/03/2020 02:00:00", de ahí el error *HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3*. Así pues, la solución fue simplemente modificar ese valor a "29/03/2020 03:00:00".

Por lo visto es un [bug en el driver de Java](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96276), aunque existe una opción preventiva ([ver post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352091/2131029)), que pasa por establecer el parámetro lenient de Calendar a false, de modo que si se intenta insertar un valor fecha y hora incorrecto lanza una excepción. Calendar por defecto es permisivo con las fechas que le introducimos, por lo que si intentasemos cargar una fecha incorrecta, por ejemplo 32 de enero, internamente trataría de corregirla a 1 de febrero ([ver enlace](https://dosideas.com/wiki/Fechas_En_Java)).